# Giving an IAM User full access

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

Should an IAM User say called User1 be given full access like so:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "*",
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

Could it also be used to create Amazon API calls? Is this a security risk or should I create another user just to access the Amazpn API Gateway?

Comment: Use least privileges policy, and don't give full permission to user1. For API-GW you don't need any permission if you want.

Comment: Yeah I will adjust the user priveleges. For API GW use AWS Lambda, I though I needed the 2 permissions here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/setting-up.html

Comment: The permission for Lambda are defined in the API-GW. The API-GW itself can be open or other authentication options (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/use-custom-authorizer.html)

Answer (score 0):

You should never give an IAM user full privileges. So many things could go wrong, and yes it may very well be a security risk.

If you need to manage (create, configure, or deploy) your API in API Gateway with this IAM user, you can give the user this policy:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "apigateway:*"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:apigateway:*::/*"
    }
  ]
}
```

Or, if you only need to invoke the API, you can use this policy:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "execute-api:Invoke"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api:*:*:*"
    }
  ]
}
```